# How to implement this gitignore scenario?

Tags: git, gitignore

TLDR: I want to ignore all files in the parent folder except contents of folder1 and folder2. In the possibility, folder1 or 2 contains jpg/png files, ignore those too.

This is what I currently have in a global .gitignore.

```
*.jpg
*.png
/*
!/folder1
!/folder2
```

Thanks a lot!

example:

```
/parent-folder
  -> text1.txt (ignored)
  -> text2.txt (ignored)
  ->folder1 (NOT ignored)
    ->ex-gf.png (ignored)
    ->my-resume.docx (NOT ignored)
  ->folder2 (NOT ignored)
    ->summer-vacation2017.jpg (ignored)
    ->my-grocery-list.xlsx (NOT ignored)
```

Answer (score 1):

.gitignore settings on folders don't apply recursively. An ignored folder won't allow anything inside it to be shown because the parent folder is missing, but the reverse is not true.

You can either explicitly exempt jpg and png files in that folder:

```
!/folder1/*.png
!/folder1/*.jpg
!/folder2/*.png
!/folder2/*.jpg
```

Exempt jpg and png files in all subfolders of folders 1 and 2

```
!/folder1/**/*.png
!/folder1/**/*.jpg
!/folder2/**/*.png
!/folder2/**/*.jpg
```

Exempt the all direct children of folders 1 and 2

```
!/folder1/*
!/folder2/*
```

Or exempt the entire content all subfolders of folders 1 and 2

```
!/folder1/**/*
!/folder2/**/*
```

You can always use [git-check-ignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore) for testing and troubleshooting as you go